# What is the difference between #ifndef and #pragma once， and what does the "same file" mean?

Tags: c++

I have researched it online, someone said they are avoid to include the same file more then one time, but i still not clear enough the difference and the meaning of same file.

Thank you advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`#pragma once` is not part of the standard and may not work on all operating systems or compilers

`#ifndef` is the preferred method of only including a file only once on most OS

Other than that `#pragma once` is less prone to making mistakes that can be caused by forgetting to change header guards if you copy and paste code etc and it is less code to type.

Comment: Let's be clear, it works with GCC and clang. Linux is an OS, not a compiler.

Comment: If we're going to be clear, let's also clarify that `#pragma` is part of the standard, but `#pragma once` is not.

Comment: And of course, the reason `#pragma once` hasn't been made standard is that it cannot be reliably implemented, at least not on a networked machine using NFS or SMB.  If you're certain that all your sources will always be on a local drive (typically the case if your using Subversion or git), and you're not worried about portability beyond VC++ and g++, `#pragma once` is fine.  Otherwise, you'll want to use the include guards (possibly with `#pragma once` as well).

Comment: @JamesKanze Clang, Intel also support it. That is the Big Four right there.

Answer (score 2):

In theory, `#pragma once` is **platform specific** and `#ifndef` style include guards are **the only Standard compliant way** to ensure header uniqueness through the preprocessor.

However, in practice, all major compilers (gcc, Clang, Visual C++, Intel) support it on all major platforms (Linux, Windows, MacOSX). Maybe some older or obscure compiler/platform combinations give you trouble, **but in practice it just works.** But caveat emptor!

The major advantage of using `#pragma once` is that **it is a lot easier to do refactorings**, since you don't have to either keep all the include guard names in sync with the file system (one common style guide obligation of defining header guards) or to use a pseudo-random string ID as include guard.

Comment: How is not having to use a pseudo-random string a disadvantage?  It can be configured to be inserted automatically when you create a new header, at least with any decent editor.  (The real disadvantage of `#pragma once` is that it can't be implemented reliably where networked file systems are concerned.)

Comment: @JamesKanze OK, with some IDE support random strings can be made to work, but it's a minor hassle nevertheless. However, I don't understand why the fact that the FS is networked should even matter, that should be an implementation detail abstracted away by the OS.

Comment: Once you're using a remote file system, it's impossible to know (with 100% reliability) whether two filenames or paths ultimately resolve to the same file or not.  (The OS doesn't care.  It will treat them as two separate files.  But they might not be.)  It's a corner case, but one you should probably keep in mind if you intend to forgo the include guards entirely.

Comment: @JamesKanze I trust your experience in this, but it sounds like that if the OS cannot reliably resolve filenames, pathnames or links, that such an OS is buggy. Any FS over multiple disks -networked or not- has to guarantee coherence and integrity.

Comment: The OS doesn't have enough information.  It ensured the coherency and integrity of what it controls, no more, no less.  (But coherency and integrity aren't the issue.  The issue is that you can have more than one path leading to the same file, and there's no way to know it.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `#pragma once` when you are addressing a specific compiler, `#pragma once` is non-standards and is specific to some specific C compilers whereas #ifndef/#define/#endif works on almost every C compiler. **#pragma once reduces possibilities for bugs.**

From [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once):

> In the C and C++ programming languages, **#pragma once is a non-standard**
>   but widely supported preprocessor directive designed to cause the
>   current source file to be included only once in a single compilation.
>   Thus, #pragma once serves the same purpose as #include guards, but
>   with several advantages, including: less code, avoidance of name
>   clashes, and sometimes improved compile speed.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once)

Comment: Remember that even on some compilers which support it (like g++), it can't be made to work reliably on a networked file system.